# Build hangs on "Target Environment update started"

Tags: genexus

I have a couple of projects, one created with genexus 17U6 and one with 17U10 that run extremely slowly. In particular they hang several minutes on "Target Environment update started" when building. Both projects use WWP, other projects work fine. I've also tried creating new projects and importing objects from old ones, but the problem persists. What can it depend on? Is there any way to see what is slowing them down?

EDIT: Logging of the build

```
2022-12-12 17:55:43,654 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Acquiring Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:55:44,043 [1] INFO  GeneXus - Flag OFF C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10\webvalid.flag
2022-12-12 17:55:44,330 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Acquiring Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:55:44,716 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Product '1', Version '27' [Callback=True]
2022-12-12 17:55:44,721 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Licensed without restrictions.
2022-12-12 17:55:50,379 [1] INFO  GeneXus - == Pattern generation (WorkWithPlusWBottoni) started ==
2022-12-12 17:55:50,381 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Acquiring Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:55:50,461 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Acquiring Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:55:55,269 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Releasing Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:55:57,476 [1] INFO  GeneXus - Saving Web Panel 'WBottoni'... 
2022-12-12 17:55:57,520 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Acquiring Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:56:03,135 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Releasing Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:56:03,135 [1] INFO  GeneXus - succeeded.
2022-12-12 17:56:03,344 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Releasing Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:56:03,344 [1] INFO  GeneXus - == Pattern generation (WorkWithPlusWBottoni) ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 17:56:06,998 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Releasing Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:56:07,014 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Releasing Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:56:07,201 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - BuildCommandFactory.Create(BuildCalled, ContinueOnErrorGeneration, BuildProcess, Execute, ConcurrentWinte)
2022-12-12 17:56:07,396 [1] INFO  GeneXus - ---> Command: RunMainObject - Elapsed time: 00:00:24.9896692
2022-12-12 17:56:07,632 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Run WBottoni started ==
2022-12-12 17:56:07,724 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - Acquiring CopyModel lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:56:07,981 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - [ModuleManager] Build using GeneXus module version '3.10.4.160901'
2022-12-12 17:56:08,064 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - Acquiring Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:56:08,091 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - Acquiring Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:56:08,191 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Copy Module 'GeneXus' started ==
2022-12-12 17:56:08,260 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Copy Module 'GeneXus' ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 17:56:08,317 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - Acquiring CopyModel lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 17:56:08,407 [14] INFO  GeneXus - Flag OFF C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10\docker.flag
2022-12-12 17:56:08,615 [14] INFO  GeneXus - Flag OFF C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10\TimeOnlyCompatibility.flag
2022-12-12 17:56:09,618 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Target Environment update started ==
2022-12-12 17:58:57,203 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> CopyModelCommand:
with tgt as (select * from ModelEntityVersion where ModelId = @ModelIdTarget) merge tgt
using (select * from ModelEntityVersion where ModelId = @ModelIdSource) src
on tgt.EntityTypeId = src.EntitytypeId and tgt.EntityId = src.EntityId
when not matched by target
then insert values(@ModelIdTarget, EntityTypeId, EntityId, EntityVersionId, @Timestamp, ModelEntityVersionName, ModelEntityVersionDescription, ModelParentEntityTypeId, ModelParentEntityId, ModelUserId)
when matched and (tgt.EntityVersionId != src.EntityVersionId or tgt.ModelParentEntityId != src.ModelParentEntityId or tgt.ModelParentEntityTypeId != src.ModelParentEntityTypeId)
then update set tgt.EntityVersionId = src.EntityVersionId, tgt.ModelEntityVersionName = src.ModelEntityVersionName, tgt.ModelEntityVersionDescription = src.ModelEntityVersionDescription, tgt.ModelEntityVersionTimestamp = @Timestamp, tgt.ModelParentEntityId = src.ModelParentEntityId, tgt.ModelParentEntityTypeId = src.ModelParentEntityTypeId, tgt.ModelUserId = src.ModelUserId
when not matched by source
then delete;
ModelIdSource:1
ModelIdTarget:2
Timestamp:12/12/2022 16:56:09
 - Elapsed time: 00:02:47.3150027
2022-12-12 17:58:57,250 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> CopyModelCommand:
update ModelEntityVersion set ModelEntityVersionTimestamp = @Timestamp from ModelEntityVersion mev inner join
(
    select mcr.ModelId, mcr.FromEntityTypeId, mcr.FromEntityId from
        (select ModelId, ToEntityTypeId, ToEntityId, FromEntityTypeId, FromEntityId from ModelCrossReference where ModelId = @ModelIdTarget and ReferenceType >= @ReferenceType and ToEntityTypeId in (12,13,14,15,16,17,6,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,32,32,32,33,34,35,36,36,36,37,38,39,40,41,41,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,8,59,60,61,62,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69)) as mcr
    left outer join
        (select @ModelIdTarget as ModelId, EntityTypeId, EntityId from ModelEntityVersion where ModelId = @ModelIdSource and EntityTypeId in (12,13,14,15,16,17,6,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,32,32,32,33,34,35,36,36,36,37,38,39,40,41,41,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,8,59,60,61,62,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69)) mevTo
    on mcr.ModelId = mevTo.ModelId and mcr.ToEntityTypeId = mevTo.EntityTypeId and mcr.ToEntityId = mevTo.EntityId
    where mevTo.ModelId is null
) as mcr on mev.ModelId = mcr.ModelId and mev.EntityTypeId = mcr.FromEntityTypeId and mev.EntityId = mcr.FromEntityId
where mev.ModelId = @ModelIdTarget and mev.EntityTypeId in (12,13,14,15,16,17,6,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,32,32,32,33,34,35,36,36,36,37,38,39,40,41,41,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,8,59,60,61,62,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69)
ModelIdSource:1
ModelIdTarget:2
Timestamp:12/12/2022 16:56:09
ReferenceType:2
 - Elapsed time: 00:00:00.0487742
2022-12-12 18:02:07,296 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> CopyModelCommand:
with tgt as (select * from ModelCrossReference where ModelId = @ModelIdTarget) merge tgt
using (select * from ModelCrossReference where ModelId = @ModelIdSource) src
on tgt.ToEntityTypeId = src.ToEntityTypeId and tgt.ToEntityId = src.ToEntityId and tgt.FromEntityTypeId = src.FromEntityTypeId and tgt.FromEntityId = src.FromEntityId and tgt.LinkType = src.LinkType and tgt.LinkTypeDetailId = src.LinkTypeDetailId
when not matched by target
then insert values(@ModelIdTarget, ToEntityTypeId, ToEntityId, FromEntityTypeId, FromEntityId, LinkType, LinkTypeDetailId, LinkTypeInfo, ReferenceType)
when matched and (tgt.LinkTypeInfo != src.LinkTypeInfo or tgt.ReferenceType != src.ReferenceType)
then update set tgt.LinkTypeInfo = src.LinkTypeInfo, tgt.ReferenceType = src.ReferenceType
when not matched by source
then delete;
ModelIdSource:1
ModelIdTarget:2
 - Elapsed time: 00:03:10.0350689
2022-12-12 18:02:07,304 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> CommandEngine.CopyModel - Elapsed time: 00:05:57.4227656
2022-12-12 18:02:07,883 [14] ERROR GeneXus - Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
2022-12-12 18:02:07,884 [14] ERROR GeneXus - Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Tempo di attesa scaduto
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Artech.Udm.Layers.Data.SQL.CustomCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Artech.Udm.Layers.Data.SQL.SQLCommands.ExecuteCopyModelCommand(String sqlCommand, Int32 modelIdSource, Int32 modelIdTarget, QueryParm[] queryParms)
   at Artech.Udm.Layers.Data.SQL.SQLCommands.Artech.Udm.Architecture.Common.IUdmCommandEngine.CopyModel(Int32 modelIdSource, Int32 modelIdTarget, CopyModelOptions options, DateTime timestamp, Int32 lowerWeakExternalRefType, IEnumerable`1 objectTypesIds)
   at Artech.Udm.Framework.UdmKnowledgeBase.CopyModel(Model source, Model target, CopyModelOptions options, IEnumerable`1 objectTypes, IEnumerable`1 copyOutputIds)
ClientConnectionId:48d68e66-87c8-47f0-82bc-dbfd18a17c11
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11
2022-12-12 18:02:07,923 [14] ERROR GeneXus - Tempo di attesa scaduto
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Tempo di attesa scaduto
2022-12-12 18:02:19,224 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> CopyModelCommand:
delete tgt from (select * from ModelEntityOutput where ModelId = @ModelIdTarget and OutputTypeId in (1711,1712,400,6192,1501,1502,1503,1504,1505,1506,1507,1508,1509,1510)) as tgt left join
(select EntityTypeId, EntityId, OutputEntityVersionId, OutputTypeId, OutputTypeVersion, OutputTimestamp from ModelEntityOutput where ModelId = @ModelIdSource and OutputTypeId in (1711,1712,400,6192,1501,1502,1503,1504,1505,1506,1507,1508,1509,1510)) src
on tgt.EntityTypeId = src.EntityTypeId and tgt.EntityId = src.EntityId and tgt.OutputEntityVersionId = src.OutputEntityVersionId and tgt.OutputTypeId = src.OutputTypeId and tgt.OutputTypeVersion = src.OutputTypeVersion
where src.OutputTimestamp is null or tgt.OutputTimestamp <> src.OutputTimestamp
ModelIdSource:1
ModelIdTarget:2
 - Elapsed time: 00:00:00.0258485
2022-12-12 18:02:19,242 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> CopyModelCommand:
insert into ModelEntityOutput (ModelId, EntityTypeId, EntityId, OutputEntityVersionId, OutputTypeId, OutputTypeVersion, OutputTimestamp, OutputData)
select @ModelIdTarget as ModelId, src.EntityTypeId, src.EntityId, src.OutputEntityVersionId, src.OutputTypeId, src.OutputTypeVersion, src.OutputTimestamp, src.OutputData from ModelEntityOutput src where src.ModelId = @ModelIdSource and src.OutputTypeId in (1711,1712,400,6192,1501,1502,1503,1504,1505,1506,1507,1508,1509,1510) and not exists
(select 1 from ModelEntityOutput tgt where tgt.ModelId = @ModelIdTarget and tgt.EntityTypeId = src.EntityTypeId and tgt.EntityId = src.EntityId and tgt.OutputEntityVersionId = src.OutputEntityVersionId and tgt.OutputTypeId = src.OutputTypeId and tgt.OutputTypeVersion = src.OutputTypeVersion)
ModelIdSource:1
ModelIdTarget:2
 - Elapsed time: 00:00:00.0173852
2022-12-12 18:02:19,242 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> CommandEngine.CopyModelOutput - Elapsed time: 00:00:00.0573971
2022-12-12 18:02:19,242 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> UdmKnowledgeBase.CopyModel - Elapsed time: 00:06:09.6155646
2022-12-12 18:02:19,300 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - Acquiring Saving lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 18:02:19,881 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - *****TypeConverter 'UserInterfaceTypeConverter' doesn't support ConvertTo KMGuidString
2022-12-12 18:02:19,882 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - *****TypeConverter 'GeneratedLanguageConverter' doesn't support ConvertTo KMGuidString
2022-12-12 18:02:19,884 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - *****TypeConverter 'DbmsCustomTypeConverter' doesn't support ConvertTo KMGuidString
2022-12-12 18:02:20,256 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> CopyModel.ModelCopying - Elapsed time: 00:00:00.9954385
2022-12-12 18:02:20,276 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> CopyModel.ModelCopied - Elapsed time: 00:00:00.0188513
2022-12-12 18:02:20,276 [14] INFO  GeneXus - ---> CopyModel - Elapsed time: 00:06:10.6569293
2022-12-12 18:02:20,277 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Target Environment update ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 18:02:20,289 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - Releasing CopyModel lock for RTSNET\nicola.pilli
2022-12-12 18:02:20,327 [14] INFO  GeneXus - Building changed objects list
2022-12-12 18:02:20,854 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - Web Panel 'WBottoni' has no specified date for generator CSharpWeb and output 115
2022-12-12 18:02:21,965 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - [Running] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10\Genexus.msbuild" /t:Open;SpecifierDaemon /p:GXInstall="C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10" /p:KBPath="C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b" /p:MutexName=Specifier.BuildWait.Mutex.14664.0 /p:SegmentName=Specifier.BuildWait.Segment.14664.0 /p:StateGuid="061b7d51-92dc-42c9-bf42-fa43214630cf" /p:GXProcessId=14664 /p:ModelId=2 /p:GenId=0 /p:PackagesCatalog="C:\ProgramData\GeneXus\GeneXus\17\packages.143920.xml" /p:ProductInfo="GeneXus;GeneXus;17;"
2022-12-12 18:02:22,003 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - [Running] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10\Genexus.msbuild" /t:Open;SpecifierDaemon /p:GXInstall="C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10" /p:KBPath="C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b" /p:MutexName=Specifier.BuildWait.Mutex.14664.0 /p:SegmentName=Specifier.BuildWait.Segment.14664.0 /p:StateGuid="061b7d51-92dc-42c9-bf42-fa43214630cf" /p:GXProcessId=14664 /p:ModelId=2 /p:GenId=0 /p:PackagesCatalog="C:\ProgramData\GeneXus\GeneXus\17\packages.143920.xml" /p:ProductInfo="GeneXus;GeneXus;17;"
2022-12-12 18:02:22,072 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Specification started ==
2022-12-12 18:02:22,450 [7] DEBUG GeneXus - Microsoft (R) Build Engine versione 4.8.4084.0
2022-12-12 18:02:22,451 [7] DEBUG GeneXus - [Microsoft .NET Framework versione 4.0.30319.42000]
2022-12-12 18:02:22,451 [7] DEBUG GeneXus - Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.
2022-12-12 18:02:22,466 [22] DEBUG GeneXus - Microsoft (R) Build Engine versione 4.8.4084.0
2022-12-12 18:02:22,466 [22] DEBUG GeneXus - [Microsoft .NET Framework versione 4.0.30319.42000]
2022-12-12 18:02:22,466 [22] DEBUG GeneXus - Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.
2022-12-12 18:02:22,543 [7] DEBUG GeneXus - Compilazione avviata 12/12/2022 18:02:22.
2022-12-12 18:02:22,543 [22] DEBUG GeneXus - Compilazione avviata 12/12/2022 18:02:22.
2022-12-12 18:02:26,126 [17] DEBUG GeneXus - SpecifierDaemon:
2022-12-12 18:02:28,627 [22] DEBUG GeneXus - Progetto "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10\Genexus.msbuild" sul nodo 1 (destinazioni: Open;SpecifierDaemon).
2022-12-12 18:02:28,627 [22] DEBUG GeneXus - Open:
2022-12-12 18:02:28,630 [7] DEBUG GeneXus - Progetto "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10\Genexus.msbuild" sul nodo 1 (destinazioni: Open;SpecifierDaemon).
2022-12-12 18:02:28,630 [7] DEBUG GeneXus - Open:
2022-12-12 18:02:28,806 [11] INFO  GeneXus -  Specifying WBottoni ...
2022-12-12 18:02:31,425 [22] DEBUG GeneXus - SpecifierDaemon:
2022-12-12 18:02:31,425 [34] INFO  GeneXus - Processing inferred calls...
2022-12-12 18:02:32,432 [14] INFO  GeneXus - Generating Resources...
2022-12-12 18:02:35,498 [14] INFO  GeneXus - Success
2022-12-12 18:02:39,283 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Specification ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 18:02:39,433 [STP SmartThreadPool Thread #0] DEBUG GeneXus - [Running] C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10\Genexus.msbuild" /t:Open;GeneratorDaemon /p:GXInstall="C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10" /p:KBPath="C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b" /p:MutexName=Generator.BuildWait.Mutex.14664.15 /p:SegmentName=Generator.BuildWait.Segment.14664.15 /p:StateGuid="061b7d51-92dc-42c9-bf42-fa43214630cf" /p:GXProcessId=14664 /p:ModelId=2 /p:GenId=15 /p:PackagesCatalog="C:\ProgramData\GeneXus\GeneXus\17\packages.143920.xml" /p:ProductInfo="GeneXus;GeneXus;17;"
2022-12-12 18:02:39,449 [STP SmartThreadPool Thread #0] INFO  GeneXus - == Default (.NET Framework) Generation started ==
2022-12-12 18:02:39,816 [34] DEBUG GeneXus - Microsoft (R) Build Engine versione 4.8.4084.0
2022-12-12 18:02:39,816 [34] DEBUG GeneXus - [Microsoft .NET Framework versione 4.0.30319.42000]
2022-12-12 18:02:39,816 [34] DEBUG GeneXus - Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.
2022-12-12 18:02:39,981 [34] DEBUG GeneXus - Compilazione avviata 12/12/2022 18:02:39.
2022-12-12 18:02:44,129 [34] DEBUG GeneXus - Progetto "C:\Program Files (x86)\GeneXus\GeneXus17-U10\Genexus.msbuild" sul nodo 1 (destinazioni: Open;GeneratorDaemon).
2022-12-12 18:02:44,129 [17] DEBUG GeneXus - Open:
2022-12-12 18:02:50,632 [33] DEBUG GeneXus - GeneratorDaemon:
2022-12-12 18:02:50,998 [34] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\wbottoni.cs
2022-12-12 18:02:51,157 [34] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\wbottoni.js
2022-12-12 18:02:51,300 [34] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\gxcfg.js
2022-12-12 18:02:51,344 [35] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\GXCFG.WEB
2022-12-12 18:02:51,616 [35] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\client.exe.config
2022-12-12 18:02:52,033 [17] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\bldDevelopermenu.cs
2022-12-12 18:02:52,181 [17] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\bldwbottoni.cs
2022-12-12 18:02:52,304 [17] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\genexus.programs.common.rsp
2022-12-12 18:02:52,313 [17] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\exe.bld
2022-12-12 18:02:52,320 [17] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\winexe.bld
2022-12-12 18:02:52,328 [17] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\library.bld
2022-12-12 18:02:52,338 [17] INFO  GeneXus - Generating to NetModel\web\bld15.info
2022-12-12 18:02:52,492 [STP SmartThreadPool Thread #0] INFO  GeneXus - == Default (.NET Framework) Generation ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 18:02:52,772 [STP SmartThreadPool Thread #0] INFO  GeneXus - Compressing static files...
2022-12-12 18:02:53,441 [STP SmartThreadPool Thread #0] INFO  GeneXus - Success
2022-12-12 18:02:54,926 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == WBottoni Compilation for Default (.NET Framework) started ==
2022-12-12 18:02:54,936 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - BuildCommand: gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldwbottoni.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:54,940 [14] INFO  GeneXus - gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldwbottoni.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:54,940 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - ExecuteCommand: gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldwbottoni.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:57,662 [33] INFO  GeneXus - Compiling wbottoni...success
2022-12-12 18:02:57,676 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == WBottoni Compilation for Default (.NET Framework) ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 18:02:57,676 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Home Compilation for Default (.NET Framework) started ==
2022-12-12 18:02:57,684 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - BuildCommand: gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldhome.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:57,686 [14] INFO  GeneXus - gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldhome.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:57,686 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - ExecuteCommand: gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldhome.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:58,341 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Home Compilation for Default (.NET Framework) ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 18:02:58,341 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == CittaWW Compilation for Default (.NET Framework) started ==
2022-12-12 18:02:58,346 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - BuildCommand: gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldcittaww.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:58,348 [14] INFO  GeneXus - gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldcittaww.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:58,348 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - ExecuteCommand: gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldcittaww.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:59,022 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == CittaWW Compilation for Default (.NET Framework) ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 18:02:59,022 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == ClienteWW Compilation for Default (.NET Framework) started ==
2022-12-12 18:02:59,030 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - BuildCommand: gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldclienteww.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:59,037 [14] INFO  GeneXus - gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldclienteww.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:59,038 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - ExecuteCommand: gxexec "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\bldclienteww.cs" -r:GxBaseBuilder.dll -arg:csc="C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\csc.exe"
2022-12-12 18:02:59,826 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == ClienteWW Compilation for Default (.NET Framework) ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 18:02:59,827 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Web config update started ==
2022-12-12 18:02:59,834 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - ExecuteCommand: virtualdir.exe http://localhost/TestVersione17U10b.NETEnvironment/ "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web" -apppool "ASP.NET V4.0" -fwVer v4.0
2022-12-12 18:03:00,197 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - BuildCommand: "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\UpdConfigWeb.exe"
2022-12-12 18:03:00,202 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - ExecuteCommand: "C:\Models\TestVersione17U10b\NetModel\web\UpdConfigWeb.exe"
2022-12-12 18:03:00,428 [15] INFO  GeneXus - Updating web config ...
2022-12-12 18:03:00,514 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Web config update ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 18:03:00,571 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Execution started ==
2022-12-12 18:03:00,597 [14] DEBUG GeneXus - BuildCommand: WEB:http://localhost/TestVersione17U10b.NETEnvironment/wbottoni.aspx
2022-12-12 18:03:01,000 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Execution ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 18:03:01,064 [14] INFO  GeneXus - == Run WBottoni ended successfully ==
2022-12-12 18:03:01,182 [1] INFO  GeneXus - Reloading Web Panel 'WBottoni'...
2022-12-12 18:03:01,205 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Releasing object WBottoni from editing
2022-12-12 18:03:02,699 [1] DEBUG GeneXus - Locking object WBottoni for editing
2022-12-12 18:03:04,264 [1] INFO  GeneXus - Done
2022-12-12 18:03:04,312 [1] INFO  GeneXus - ---> Command: BuildCommandWrapperUI - Elapsed time: 00:06:56.9186902
```

Answer (score 1):

What value do you have at Environment Level > property: Build Mode?

I had the same problem and it solved when switching the value of this property from **MSBuild** to **Standard**.

You can read more about this property on the following link: https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?3936,Build+Mode+property+for+.NET+generator

Comment: I tried but without success, even after a rebuild the waiting times are still long. What else can I try?

Comment: Killing all the "MSBuild.exe" tasks in the Task Manger, closing and reopening Genexus and building again

Answer (score 1):

The `Target Environment update` step is a very IO intensive step, that needs to compare the state of the internal model structure of the version being built, with the last built state of the current environment.
This synchronization is performed directly in the KB's DB with a series of SQL statements.

If you [turn the GeneXus log on](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?23257,GeneXus%20Log), and run GeneXus with the `/MeasureCommandTime` [command line argument](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6740,GeneXus%20command%20line%20parameters), the statements run during the synchronization are print in the log, with detailed information on how long it took to run each statement. If you post that information here I may be able to provide some further insight into why the synchronization may be taking too long.

In any case, I would advise you to check how the SQL server instance of the KB's DB is performing, for instance check if it's constrained in memory usage, or check if the DB files are stored in a drive with slow read/write speeds.

Comment: I added the loggin according your answer. It looks like something about sql connection (I think is it about the KB database?), but I don't understand more than it. The project works, there are other projects in the same server, but it's like it's going in timeout during the build.

Comment: The optimized synchronization between the version and the environment is timing out, and it's falling back to the non-optimized algorithm that deletes all information in the environment, and inserts all the information from the version.
I'd suggest you report the issue to the customer support team, so that we can analyze the specifics of this issue.